# logging using log4j into a separate files along with on to console

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my log4j.properties file

```
# Define the root logger
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, toConsole

# Define the console appender
log4j.appender.toConsole=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.toConsole.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.toConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] - %c.%M - %m%n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.success=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.success.File=logs/success.log
log4j.appender.success.Append=false
log4j.appender.success.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.success.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] - %c.%M - %m%n

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.failure=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.failure.File=logs/failure.log
log4j.appender.failure.Append=false
log4j.appender.failure.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.failure.layout.conversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss} %5p [%t] - %c.%M - %m%n

log4j.category.successLogger=DEBUG, success
log4j.additivity.successLogger=false

log4j.category.failureLogger=WARN, failure
log4j.additivity.failureLogger=false
```

and in java class I'm using it as:

```
static final Logger successLog = Logger.getLogger("successLogger");
static final Logger failureLog = Logger.getLogger("failureLogger");
```

and using it as:

```
successLog.warn("Connection is not established");
failureLog.error("Exception",e);
```

I'm able to get success.log and failure.log file but I was not able to print it on console. Right now, I need to print it on console as well (as just as the flow of our program i.e., need to print parallelly on console while writing to respective logs) and in future I may require only to print the statements only which are eligible to write into success.log
How can I achieve it ???? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By default Log4j uses the appenders explicitly configured for a logger **and** the appenders of the parent logger. This behavior is called *"additivity"* by Log4j. You disabled it with the lines:

```
log4j.additivity.successLogger=false
log4j.additivity.failureLogger=false
```

You just need to restore additivity by deleting these lines or setting the value to `true`.

Alternatively, you can list multiple appenders for a given logger:

```
log4j.category.successLogger=DEBUG, success, toConsole
```